# Is there a way to change Notification Center's orientation?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

My client asked me to rotate just labels and buttons when device is rotated. I turned auto-rotation off and made some affine transforms on the labels and buttons during the device rotation. But iOS thinks my app is in portrait orientation always, so the Notification Center can be dragged with finger from upper part of iPhone/iPad only and it is in portrait orientation always. Is there a way to change Notification Center orientation?

Comment: No there isn't, but I really can't understand the reason about applying a sort of rotation when you have the default one. You should work on the default rotation mechanism and customize that.

Comment: I don't know another way to make all UI elements stay at their positions except text during the rotation.